# Ubuntu 16.04.3 intel skylake i915 external monitor not detected

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-16.04, drivers

My external monitor, connected via HDMI was working fine but now is not being detected (it says 'No video input'). I'm pretty sure I didn't make any changes to make it stop - it was working on the same setup yesterday.

I'm a pretty new linux user and also don't know much about graphics hardware and drivers. Appreciate any help, I'd like to understand what's going on!

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 kernel 4.10.0-33

`lshw -c video` gives:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:124 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I've tried booting from grub into kernel 4.8.0 and the monitor still wasn't detected.

I've also tried to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

I've also tried running the Intel graphics update tool and this also hasn't solved anything.

EDIT: It seems like I get the 'No video input' probelm if I plug in the HDMI cord before the computer has finished booting.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only answer one can give here based on the available information is, try checking the display cables, and, if that doesn't help, file a bug. Debugging display problems like this can be fairly involved, with several cycles of requesting and providing more information. That doesn't really work all that well here.

The alternatives for filing the bug are [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and [drm/i915 upstream](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs). Upstream has the best knowledge about the driver and the hardware, but, depending on the issue, you might be expected to build and run the userspace components or the kernel from upstream git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the problem and solve it with exactly the same card (i had same lshw -c video) by searching the NVIDIA X-Server settings (search inside apps) on my Ubuntu 16 LTS and activate the NVIDIA drivers for this card (I have a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX)

After i log out and i have a bad errors display and i was blocked " this computer is running in low display mode" .

I just switch off the computer and restart it...and taatatatat HDMI was working and was able to display on my external Sansumg 27''

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as OP. lshw not showing HDMI port, nada. Reinstalling xserver* did not work either.

May the gods of stack overflow smile upon you for that EDIT line, because plugging only after boot was complete, it did work for me as well.

This is quite interesting, as I am running 20.04. This issue came out of nowhere, just turned on the computer and voila, it was not working. There had been no updates, no changes that could affect this during previous session.

Would love to know if someone else has bumped into this problem.